# Show that $ M_f$ is a factor of $ C_f$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces, minimal-polynomials

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over a field $K$. Let $f:V \rightarrow V$ be a linear map. Let $M_f$ be the minimum polynomial of $f$ and let $C_f$ be the characteristic polynomial of $f$.

How can you show that $M_f$ is a factor of $C_f$ using the Cayley-Hamilton equation?

Comment: -1. I don't like to be talked in the imperative.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro changed

Comment: Wow, after 4 years! Great.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro i didnt pick it before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We write the Euclidean division of $C_f$ by $M_f$: there's $Q,R\in \Bbb K[x]$ such that
$$C_f=QM_f+R$$
and $\deg R<\deg M_f$. Now by the Cayely-Hamilton theorem we have $C_f(f)=0$ and since $M_f(f)=0$ then we see that
$$R(f)=0$$
so $R=0$ otherwise we have a contradiction with the fact that $M_f$ is the minimal polynomial. Conclude.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the main facts:

- $J = \{ P \in K[x] : P(f) = 0 \}$ is an ideal of $K[x]$, which is a PID.
- $J = \langle M_f \rangle$, (almost) by definition.
- $C_f(f)=0 \implies C_f \in J$